# How does "to come across" work in this context?

Tags: vocabulary

Although I know what *come across* means, I can not understand the whole meaning of the sentence below, or I can not understand what *come across* means here!

> He came across very badly in the interview. He never looked at them.

Comment: See [Oxford Online Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come?q=come+across+as#come__21), definition 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "come across" referes to the perception of the others in his presence, in this case, the interviewer.

The applicant may think he did very well, but the interview didn't like that he never looked up so he, or his actions, *came across* badly.

Another way to express this would be:

> The applicant never looked at the interviewer so he showed a bad attitude.

It does not imply any physical movement.